Request Timeout Error while uploading to s3 in aws sdk v3 in local environment
I am facing an issue in my local environment while uploading file to s3 after migrating from aws sdk v2 to v3. But there is no issue in the deployed site.I am getting the error "Your socket connection to the server was not read from or written to within the timeout period. Idle connections will be closed.".   But this error is occurs randomly, other times the upload works fine.I have tried PutObjectCommand for small files and multipart upload for large files.The error occurs in both cases randomly.Anyone knows how to handle this?
const saveS3 = (fileName, path, target, awsBucket, contentDirectory) => {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    fs.stat(path, (err, stats) => {
      if (err) {
        return reject({
          success: false,
          message: "S3 error reading file from local source",
          fileUrl: null,
          fileName: null,
          storageType: target,
        });
      }

      const fileSize = stats.size;

      fs.readFile(path, async (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          return reject({
            success: false,
            message: "S3 error reading file from local source",
            fileUrl: null,
            fileName: null,
            storageType: target,
          });
        }
        const params = {
          Bucket: awsBucket,
          Key: `${contentDirectory}/${fileName}`,
          Body: data,
        };

        if (fileSize <= 5 * 1024 * 1024) {
          console.log("small File")
          const command = new PutObjectCommand(params);
          console.log("command",command)
          s3Client.send(command)
            .then(() => {
              console.log("inside then")
              AWSSignedURL(params.Key, awsBucket)
                .then((url) => {
                  return resolve({
                    success: true,
                    message: "File uploaded to S3",
                    fileUrl: url.url,
                    fileName: `${contentDirectory}/${fileName}`,
                    storageType: target,
                  });
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                  console.log(err);
                  return reject({
                    success: false,
                    message: "Error obtaining url",
                    fileUrl: null,
                    fileName: null,
                    storageType: target,
                  });
                });
            })
            .catch((err) => {
              return reject({
                success: false,
                message: ("S3 error uploading file to remote source :", err),
                fileUrl: null,
                fileName: null,
                storageType: target,
              });
            });
        } else {
          console.log("large File")
          const upload = new Upload({
            client: s3Client,
            params: params,
          });
          upload.done().then((data) => {
            console.log("dataaaa", data)
            AWSSignedURL(data.Key, awsBucket)
              .then((url) => {
                return resolve({
                  success: true,
                  message: "File uploaded to S3",
                  fileUrl: url.url,
                  fileName: `${contentDirectory}/${fileName}`,
                  storageType: target,
                });
              })
              .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
                return reject({
                  success: false,
                  message: "Error obtaining url",
                  fileUrl: null,
                  fileName: null,
                  storageType: target,
                });
              });
          }).catch((err) => {
            return reject({
              success: false,
              message: ("S3 error uploading file to remote source :", err),
              fileUrl: null,
              fileName: null,
              storageType: target,
            });
          });
        }
      });
    });
  });
}; 

